# How to get a square Root form an Integer

Tags: swift

So I want to pick a random Integer and get the square root from that number.
But if if use sqrt it always want me to make the integer a Double.

Is there a way to pass that barrier or to get the square root a different way?

Thank you for your answers.

[image: The Error]

Comment: convert it to a double.

Comment: Have you try something like: `print(sqrt(Double(number)))`

Comment: `func sqrt(_ value: Int) -> Double { sqrt(Double(value)) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqrt function takes double parameter
So convert your number to double

```
let doubleNumber: Double = Double(number)
print(sqrt(doubleNumber))
```

Comment: Square roots are a transcendental function, and the result is rarely an integer. Ahsan's solution of converting your integer value to a Double seems like the way to go. (voted). You could round or truncate the result back to an integer, but you'll loose a lot of useful information doing that. (The square root of 2 is ≈1.414. Rounded, the answer is 1, which is very wrong.